# Change title invoice pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

Can anybody tell me where I can change the title of the invoice pdf.
At the moment it states invoice(date and time). I want to change it to Invoice(invoicenumber)I work with magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinothavn, thnx for your answer. I looked into the coding and tried it, but unfortulnately it didnt work. But I altered some other code in the same file and that did work. I changed this:

```
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```

Into this:

```
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('Factuur_'. $invoice->getIncrementId().
                '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf')
```

And now the pdf exports with the invoicenumber.

Answer (score 0):

The file which has the invoice tile is in below path

app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Controller\Sales\Invoice.php

```
   public function pdfinvoicesAction(){
    $invoicesIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('invoice_ids');
    if (!empty($invoicesIds)) {
        $invoices = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_invoice_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $invoicesIds))
            ->load();
        if (!isset($pdf)){
            $pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);
        } else {
            $pages = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf($invoices);
            $pdf->pages = array_merge ($pdf->pages, $pages->pages);
        }

        return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
            '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

You can change

```
  return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
            '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```

to

```
return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.$invoicesIds.
            '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```